# How to start and stop timer display in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, use-ref

I am trying to create a Pomodoro timer in ReactJS. I am having trouble having the timer to stop it's countdown.

**PomView.js**

```
const PomView = () => {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(1500)    // 25 minutes
    const [start, setStart] = useState(false)
    var firstStart = useRef(true)
    var tick;

    useEffect( () => {
        if (firstStart.current) {
            console.log("first render, don't run useEffect for timer")
            firstStart.current = !firstStart.current
            return
        }

        console.log("subsequent renders")
        console.log(start)
        if (start) {
            tick = setInterval(() => {
            setTimer(timer => {
                timer = timer - 1
                console.log(timer)
                return timer       
                }
            )
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        console.log("clear interval")
        clearInterval(tick);
    }
    }, [start])

    const toggleStart = () => {
        setStart(!start)
    }


    const dispSecondsAsMins = (seconds) => {
        // 25:00 
        console.log("seconds " + seconds)
        const mins = Math.floor(seconds / 60)
        const seconds_ = seconds % 60
        return mins.toString() + ":" + ((seconds_ == 0) ? "00" : seconds_.toString())
    }

    return (
        <div className="pomView">
            <ul>
                <button className="pomBut">Pomodoro</button>
                <button className="pomBut">Short Break</button>
                <button className="pomBut">Long Break</button>
            </ul>
            <h1>{dispSecondsAsMins(timer)}</h1>
            <div className="startDiv">
                {/* event handler onClick is function not function call */}
                <button className="startBut" onClick={toggleStart}>{!start ? "START" : "STOP"}</button>
                {start && <AiFillFastForward className="ff" onClick="" />}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PomView
```

Although the `clearInterval` runs in the else portion of useEffect, the timer continues ticking. I am not sure if it is because of the asynchronous setTimer method in useEffect. I would like to know what the problem is with the code I have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store the timer ref in `tick`, but each time the component rerenders the `tick` value from the previous render is lost. You should also store `tick` as a React ref.

You are also mutating the `timer` state.

```
setTimer((timer) => {
  timer = timer - 1; // mutation
  return timer;
});
```

Just return the current value minus 1: `setTimer((timer) => timer - 1);`

Code

```
const PomView = () => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(1500); // 25 minutes
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
  const firstStart = useRef(true);
  const tick = useRef(); // <-- React ref

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstStart.current) {
      firstStart.current = !firstStart.current;
      return;
    }

    if (start) {
      tick.current = setInterval(() => { // <-- set tick ref current value
        setTimer((timer) => timer - 1);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(tick.current); // <-- access tick ref current value
    }

    return () => clearInterval(tick.current); // <-- clear on unmount!
  }, [start]);

  ...
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-start-and-stop-timer-display-in-reactjs]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am not sure what is kept and what is lost during the re-render. Whenever the react re-renders the `return` portion of the function component is run irregardless of state variable change. only the variables in `useState` and `useRef` are preserved from the previous state ?

Comment: @calveeen In your code, yes, but also values that are memoized via `useMemo` and `useCallback` hooks, and `useReducer` is similar to `useState` with regards to component state. I suggest reading through the official [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) regarding React hooks. Basically all local variables and functions are all redeclared each render cycle.

Comment: Is there also a difference between `setTimer((timer) => timer - 1);` and the way I wrote it because both code do the same thing. I am not sure what you mean by mutating the timer state

Comment: @calveeen Yes, there is a difference. While they both accomplish the same, saying `timer = timer - 1` updates the previous state value, it'd be similar to doing `timer--`. It would be preferable to declare a new variable, update and return it, i.e. `const newTimer = timer - 1; return newTimer;`. In React you want to avoid state mutations. It seems benign here, but with more complex state it can really wreak havok and be difficult to track down and debug.

Comment: I see. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

```
useEffect( () => {
    const tick= setInterval(fun, 1000);
    return ()=>{
      clearInterval(tick);
    }
}, [])
```

useEffect has it's own release way.